# "besides" and "except for" in British English

Tags: prepositions, british-english, dialect

Can "besides" and "except for" have the same meaning in the following in British English?

> The house is clean, besides/except for the kitchen.

Comment: Oxford Languages gives the example "I have no other family besides my parents".

Comment: @KateBunting That example has "besides" after a negative word, a position where "except for" and "besides" are more or less interchangeable. But my sentence has a different environment.

Comment: _Except for, besides, apart from, not counting_ - they all mean the same, whether the statement is negative or positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two words can seem interchangeable and may deliver the same meaning in specific contexts, but the definitions of 'besides' and 'except' are very different and give them each unique usage.

- 'Besides' means *in addition to* or *as well as*.
- An 'exception' is an *exclusion*.

At root meaning, they couldn't be more opposite. One includes, the other excludes.

An example of where they can mean the same, despite the difference, would be:

> - I have no family *except* my parents.
> - I have no family *besides* my parents.

Essentially, these mean the same thing - that your family consists of your parents and nobody else. But, the first example cites your parents as an *exception* to the statement that you have "no family", whereas the second is saying that your parents are your family but there are no others to add to that.

Your own example makes no sense with 'besides'. This is because the kitchen is an *exception* to the original statement, but it does not make sense to say the house is clean *in addition to* the kitchen, which is also part of the house.

You could say, for example, "*Besides the kitchen, I have not cleaned the house*" which would mean you have cleaned the kitchen, but not anywhere else.